# ¿Como validar la inserción de registros repetidos en MySql y Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Requiero validar si el registro ya existe para no ser insertado nuevamente, además me gustaría que me dijeran como centrar los mensajes(echo) ya que me aparecen abajo de la pantalla de mi monitor.
Este es  mi código PHP.

```
<?php

try {
    $usuario  = "698193_admin";
    $password = "1234admin";
    $conn     = new PDO('mysql:host=fdb3.runhosting.com;dbname=698193_admin', $usuario, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $Code     = $_POST['Code'];
    $consulta = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM  Usuarios WHERE Code=" . $Code);
    $consulta->execute();

    if ($consulta->rowCount() == 1) {
        echo 'Ya  existe un Usuario con este  código';
    } else {
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Usuarios(Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario) VALUES (:Code, :user, :Pass, :TipoUsuario)");
        $sql->bindParam(':Code', $_POST['Code']);
        $sql->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
        $sql->bindParam(':Pass', $_POST['Pass']);
        $sql->bindParam(':TipoUsuario', $_POST['TipoUsuario']);
        $sql->execute();

        echo 'Usuario  agregado   correctamente';
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'No  se pudo  agregar  el Usuario ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Agrego  también  mi  código  android.
Creo que ahora el error es aquí.

*AddUsuario.java*

```
    private void addUsuario() {

    final String Code = et1.getText().toString().trim();
    final String User = et2.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Pass = et3.getText().toString().trim();
    final String TipoUsuario = muestraUser.getSelectedItem().toString();

    class AddUsuario extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(addUsuario.this, "Adding...", "Wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(addUsuario.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_CODE, Code);
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_USUARIO, User);
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_PASS, Pass);
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_TIPOUSER, TipoUsuario);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD_USER, params);
            return res;
        }
    }

    AddUsuario ae = new AddUsuario();
    ae.execute();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Sofia veo que hay una etiqueta de android usas android?...si usas php utilizas el patron MVC?...si lo usas esta respuesta te podra servir, si no de igual manera intentalo...

Comment: usa una condicional que verifique o sea que haga una comparacion antes de recuperar los datos desde la base de datos o antes de actualizar con una condicional resolves es problema compara el valor nuevo con cada registro de la tabla en cuestion tenes que usar una condicional con un bucle ;) resuelto!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tu pregunta sobre los mensajes `Toast`, probablemente esto te sirva:

```java
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(addUsuario.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

*En [How to display Toast at center of screen.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321186/how-to-display-toast-at-center-of-screen).*

Ahora para el problema de la base de datos. Ten en cuenta que existen los [indices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) como las [claves primarias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_primaria), las columnas indizadas y las columnas únicas, etc.

Para declarar una tabla con clave primaria y columnas "únicas" puedes usar una expresión como la siguiente:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
    code INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # No puede ser nulo y se incrementa en cada inserción
    user VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    pass VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    tipo_usuario INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( code ),            # Modifica 'code' para que sea primaria
    UNIQUE KEY user_idx ( user )     # Añade un indice a 'user' llamado 'user_idx'
);
```

*Mas información en [Table creation reference.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)*

La cuestión con tener indices es que aumenta el rendimiento de tu aplicación. Al momento de insertar un nuevo usuario, si este tiene el mismo nombre falla. Si intentas hacer esto en PHP tendrás que recorrer fila por fila los resultados de la consulta para hacer la comparación. Imagina si tienes un millón de usuarios en la base de datos ! Mysql y las bases de datos usan métodos implementados a mas bajo nivel para lograr indizar las columnas y detectar si ya existe casi instantáneamente mientras que PHP no recibe filas indizadas, por lo tanto hace una búsqueda secuencial.

Entonces para validar la inserción de un dato repetido en PHP debes:

- Definir una constante para el código del error en la cabecera del archivo o en uno para todas las constantes:

```php
    define('MYSQL_ERROR_DUPLICATE_KEY', '1062');
```

*Sobre Declaración de constantes en [PHP.net.](http://php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php)*
*Información sobre códigos de error en [Server Error Codes and Messages.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html)*

- Validar el error en el bloque `catch` de la inserción:

```php
    try {
        /* Código de inserción */
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        if ($e->errorInfo[1] == MYSQL_ERROR_DUPLICATE_KEY) {
            //La inserción ha fallado por que el usuario ya existe!
        }
    }
```

*Mas información en [Detect mysql update/insertion failure due to violated unique constraint.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449540/php-detect-mysql-update-insertion-failure-due-to-violated-unique-constraint)*
*Mas información sobre las excepciones PDO en [PHP.net.](http://php.net/PDOException)*